# loop through gridview and get data key value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to loop through the rows of my gridview and retrieve the data key value of each row and then execute some code to run sql queries.   How can I get the data key value of each row in variable?  right now I am receiving an error message saying:

> value of type system.web.ui.webcontrols.datakey cannot be converted to integer.

Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim therowindex As Integer = row.RowIndex

        Dim theid As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys([therowindex])

        'execute some more code running queries using the data key value.
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx#Y500) property.

```
Dim theid As Integer = Integer.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys(therowindex).Value.ToString())
```

Answer (score 13):

You can iterate through the `.Rows` collection, and then find the row's `DataKey` value.

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    string theDataKey = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    // Do something with your index/key value
}
```